# Using minifyEnabled=true is NOT OK in development ;]

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated Android Studio to 3.5.

BTW updated the Gradle version and several libraries.

To my surprise, the application does not fit into a single DEX (uses over 73,500 methods, previously in debug version as far as I remember ~50K)

What changes have I made:

```
Kotlin 1.3.41 -> 1.3.50
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0' from 3.4.2
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1' from 4.3.0

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1' from 18.1.0
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.1.0' from 17.0.1
```

The new release APK has fewer (60) methods (26760) than the previous one.

Other problem I got:
NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN error

App using AndroidX.

app is compiling & work now OK when set

```
 debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

I imported settings from an older version of Android Studio. Maybe here is the problem?
Or there is no problem and I have to reconcile and use multiDEX (for development) and in release apk drop multiDEX?. Will multidex be better than minifyEnabled for debug version?

Changed:

```
debug {
           // minifyEnabled true
           // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
```

And is working with multiDex when I run emulator with APK >=21. 
Prior 21 API will test using release APK only.

BTW APK analyze my debug version show:
classes.dex 54806 methods
classes2.dex 1107 methods
classes3.dex 6725 methods

Total: 62638.

When I disable multiDex.
Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 73883 > 65536) ;))

Something is not right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `multiDexEnabled true` globally or for both build-types - else the release build will exceed the 64k limit of a single DEX file. debug & release build can have different method count, because these are two merged source-sets - and unused classes may also be stripped (`multiDexEnabled true` also adds it's own library). While `minifyEnabled true` for debug builds is useless ...and I really don't understand why one would intend to do that. When the non-public class/method names in the APK do not match those class names in the IDE, one might find it difficult to debug that, because breakpoints will not catch; it's alike shooting oneself into the leg.

If a single library update introduces a new dependency, this can add lots of classes & methods.

Comment: Thanks. On release i have minifyEnable so should not exceed 64K limit after minify. So for now use multiDexEnabled only for developing (debug). Strange situation that update 3 libraries so dramatically increased the number of methods

Comment: @Adam see [Generate a report of removed (or kept) code](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#usage).